# Chrome rendering SVG graph

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I have an SVG graph, made with nvd3. I'm finding that the graph is badly rendered in chrome since a couple of weeks/days (I didn't check it every day).

I have the same graph on 2 pages: 
On the first it renderers fine (every time) [image: good render]
<sub>(source: [tinygrab.com](http://new.tinygrab.com/845c7c6160928a6d2d2119492faa1b95bb1f38c17f.png))</sub>

On the second it renders badly (every time). [image: bad render]
<sub>(source: [tinygrab.com](http://new.tinygrab.com/845c7c61608e908bd48fb8bb76b7d2960cbe624696.png))</sub>

The only difference between those 2 graphs is that on the second page there is an other graph below it.
See screenshot 1 and 2.

If I open the chrome developer tools, the graph gets redrawn and is suddenly OK again...

Does anyone know of a rendering bug in Chrome? This used to work without any problems some weeks ago, so I thought it might be a bug in Chrome or something...

Comment: How are you including the graphs is it by `<object>` or `<iframe>` tags or by inline SVG within a html page. If its inline SVG are the id attributes of both graphs globally unique? As to rendering bugs all browsers have lots of those. Chrome has an open bugtracker at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: Inline SVG and the id's are globally unique

Comment: An easy fix would probably be possible by just showing and hiding the SVG (or maybe some other style changes) that makes the browser redraw it on window load event

Comment: Please file a bug at http://crbug.com, including a complete (minimal if possible) testcase.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like adding the style: `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to the SVG's fixed it.
I knew this fixes rendering problems in Chrome with position absolute / fixed, so I thought i could try it out. seems it's related, although I can't find any elements that are positioned fixed/absolute related to the SVG's...